# How can I change `grep '^2013-12-03'` to "2 days ago"?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I need to `tar` a file from 2 days ago, every day.

This is my script:

```
stat -c"%z;%n" * | \
grep '^2013-12-03' | \
grep "FPROD-LvL0-*" | \
awk -F';' '{ print $2 }' | \
xargs tar -zcvf pjpj_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d' --date='3 days ago').tar.gz
```

How can I change `grep '^2013-12-03'` to "2 days ago"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are already using the technique:

```
grep "`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '2 days ago'`"
```

Comment: backquote and $() are interchangeable, they will produce the same value, but $() is preferred because you can use nested $($()) but it's not possible to nest backquote, I use backquote because it saves me 1 keystroke, so you should use your form `$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '2 days ago')`